# Is the "ubuntu-bug" tool broken?

Tags: apport, ubuntu-bug

It asks me for a PID, even though it didn't in previous versions. If I don't provide one or if I choose "other problem", it closes saying that I need a PID.
If I put the symptoms in the terminal, it crashes saying there is no package matching the description.

I have several bugs that don't affect any of the options provided by "Ubuntu-bug" hence I would need to file it under "other problem".

Comment: You can get the PID of a running program using the `pidof <program name here>` command.

Comment: I know that. But I don't want to do that. also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/874266

Answer (score 1):

You can type the package name if you think you know what the bug is about. For example, if its nautilus causing the problem type

```
ubuntu-bug nautilus
```

in your termial or by pressing Alt+F2. Or if it is firefox then type

```
ubuntu-bug firefox
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that. The thing is that I don't want to fill the bug on any particular package, or a package I don't know.

Comment: well, in that case you can just give a descriptive bug report without the apport details. After the developers read and understand your problem, they will ask you to give apport bug report with the right package name.

Comment: riiight, what I'm saying is that apport doesn't let you do that. Although the helps says it should.